# mocking inner nested method in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In angular ag-grid jasmine how could mock inner private method getRows().

```js
onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
        testComponentParams: () => ({
        }),
    }];
    this.setColumns();

    const dataSource = {
        getRows: (args: IGetRowsParams) => {
            sortModel = args.sortModel;
            if (sortModel.length) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the closing square bracket for the `this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [`?

Comment: @AntonKrug it was missed, just updated the code.  closing just before the this.setColumns(); .